# How to loop through array one by one in php

Tags: php, arrays, api, loops, for-loop

Update: someone in comment section suggested to use JSON. How can I loop through it as in my code.

What I have tried:

```
    $jsonData = file_get_contents('au.json');
    $data = json_decode($jsonData);
    file_put_contents('au.json', json_encode($data));
    
     foreach($data as $obj) {
    
    echo '<h2>Perform the search</h2>';
    $api_call_string = 'search?entity_type=city&q='.$obj->city;
   
}
```

Is above the right way to do it? I already have data in `au.json` file.

JSON code (I have posted some of it):

```
[
    {
        "city": "Sydney", 
        "admin": "New South Wales", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "3641422", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "admin", 
        "lat": "-33.861481", 
        "lng": "151.205475", 
        "population": "4630000"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "South Melbourne", 
        "admin": "Victoria", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "93625", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "", 
        "lat": "-37.833333", 
        "lng": "144.966667", 
        "population": "4170000"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Brisbane", 
        "admin": "Queensland", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "926353", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "admin", 
        "lat": "-27.47101", 
        "lng": "153.024292", 
        "population": "1860000"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Perth", 
        "admin": "Western Australia", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "880216", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "admin", 
        "lat": "-31.95224", 
        "lng": "115.861397", 
        "population": "1532000"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Adelaide", 
        "admin": "South Australia", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "836354", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "admin", 
        "lat": "-34.928661", 
        "lng": "138.598633", 
        "population": "1145000"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Newcastle", 
        "admin": "New South Wales", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "497955", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "", 
        "lat": "-32.927792", 
        "lng": "151.784485", 
        "population": "1134616"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Gold Coast", 
        "admin": "Queensland", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "332249", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "", 
        "lat": "-28.00029", 
        "lng": "153.430878", 
        "population": "527660"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Cranbourne", 
        "admin": "Victoria", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "39419", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "", 
        "lat": "-38.1", 
        "lng": "145.283333", 
        "population": "460491"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Canberra", 
        "admin": "Australian Capital Territory", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "234032", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "primary", 
        "lat": "-35.27603", 
        "lng": "149.13435", 
        "population": "327700"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Wollongong", 
        "admin": "New South Wales", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "141725", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "", 
        "lat": "-34.424", 
        "lng": "150.893448", 
        "population": "260914"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Geelong", 
        "admin": "Victoria", 
        "country": "Australia", 
        "population_proper": "137681", 
        "iso2": "AU", 
        "capital": "", 
        "lat": "-38.153461", 
        "lng": "144.358093", 
        "population": "160991"
    }, 
    {
```

How to loop through arrays one by one in php? I am trying to first loop through `state` so I know how many times to loop through as I have 3 array after `state` listed as `state1` `state2` `state3`. So I want to loop 3 times. First I want to loop through `state1` contents, then `state2` and so on.

I tried to save the variable name and added '$' in front of it which does not seem to work as it would treat it as a string. Is there any way to loop through all of these arrays one by one? I have an api where I am trying to use this value, so I need to go through each array one at a time. For example, First it loops through `state1` (so that would be 2 times) Now it goes back to line 6  `$states=  '$'. $state[$s];`and loop through 2nd array `state2` and so on, so I can get values of each state city one by one. First state1 all cities, then state2 all cities etc. Please let me know if there is more information needed.

In short: first it will get the details of state 1 that is all of its cities and use that city values to fetch some data from the api. Now, it will get state 2 details (again cities of state 2 this time) and fetch all the details according to the value of state 2 cities
My code:

```
    $state = array("state1", "state2", "state3");
    
    $state1 = array("cityA", "cityB");
    $state2 = array("cityA", "cityB");
    $state3 = array("cityA","cityB");
    
    for ($s=0; $s<count($state); $s++) {
        $states=  '$'. $state[$s];
        
        for ($c=0; $c<count($states); $c++) {
    
    $call_string = 'testing: '.$states[$c]; //this is an api which I edited so I need the value of it here
    
      }
}
```

Comment: @KenY-N If I do that will it have all the values of that specific array? Or would it be an empty array?

Comment: it's called variable variables, `$states = ${$state[$s]}` like so. but why though, you could probably just get state lists on google to have a complete array. then you would'nt need to do those, very prone to mistakes

Comment: You just need to change `$states= ${$state[$s]};` and your code will work fine.

Comment: @Kevin I do have a state list but each state has cities, so I am trying to loop through each state cities. It's why I have seperate arrays for different state cities. Do you reckon I should have all state cities in a single array of a country?

Comment: @Sky yes of course, if they're already nested according to their state, then you wouldn't need to do those variable variable things, something like this https://gist.github.com/ahmu83/38865147cf3727d221941a2ef8c22a77 just google which country you need, im sure every state with city is already listed

Comment: @Kevin I am looking for Australia. I am not able to find similar thing on github. Could you please help?

Comment: @Kevin I found it. How can I loop through it in my code? I updated my question please have a look

Comment: @Sky with your edits this is a completely different question. I would recommend rolling this back to the original and asking a new question instead.

Comment: @Nick Okay, I will do that. Thanks.